# Whether or not the Set of 2x2 non-invertible matrices with determinant 0 form a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine whether the indicated set forms a ring under the indicated operation
$S = \{A ∈ M(2, \Bbb R) | det A = 0\}$ under matrix addition and multiplication.

So given that $S$ is the set of all $2$x$2$ matrices with entries from $\Bbb R$ with determinant $0$, how would I begin showing the ring axioms generally? Are there a few general forms of matrices with determinant $0$ so that I can begin to show closure, associativity, etc? Or is there an example from the set that shows that it does not form a ring? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let A be the matrix with upper left corner $1$, everybody else $0$. Let $B$ be the matrix with lower right corner $1$, everybody else $0$. The determinant of each of $A$ and $B$ is $0$, but the determinant of $A+B$ certainly is not $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\3 & 9\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $$A+B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 5\\5 & 13\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Nid, you asked "Or is there an example from the set that shows that it does not form a ring?"  And that is what I answered.

Comment: Sorry. I just realized that this is an example. Ok so is this suffcient though? Is it required by ring axioms $A+B$ has to also be an in $S$? The closure property is confusing me for matrices.

Comment: @Nid, it is necessary for it to be closed.